# What is the probability of getting more than 63 tails when flipping a coin 127 times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

What is the probability of getting more than 63 tails when flipping a coin 127 times?

I know that I can find the answer like this:
$$\Bigr(\sum_{i=64}^{127} \mathrm{C}_{127} ^i\Bigr) * (1/2)^{127}$$

But I have no idea how to calculate this expression. Is there any easier way to solve this problem? (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: The notation $\binom{n}{r}$ to denote the number of ways to select a subset of size $r$ from a set of size $n$ is much more common.  Your notation is frustrating since some people use $C^{r}_n$ and others use $C^n_r$ to mean the same thing as I wrote initially.

Comment: As for how to calculate the expression, a computer will help.  If you don't want to use a computer, then it would be incredibly tedious for arbitrary values.  You can however approximate it using a normal distribution quite well.  There are some special cases though, like this one, which have nice simplifications.

Comment: the normal approximation is your friend here,  it all depends on how precise you need to be,  your exact expression is easy to compute if you need exactness.

Comment: It's a trick question.

Comment: In this special case, we can determine the probability almost without any calculation. The probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ due to a symmetry-argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

If you flip $127$ times, either there will be more than $63$ heads, or more than $63$ tails, but not both.